# Can I transfer my Minecraft worlds from Minecraft PE 15.0.9 from Android tab to PS4 or XBOX one?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

I am planning to buy either PS4 or XBox One for my son who is currently using Mincecraft PE on Android Samsung Galaxy tablet running version 15.0.9. Is it possible to transfer the data/worlds from PE edition on tablet to either PS4 or XBox One? Appreciate the answers/responses.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the case. You can only transfer from PS3 to PS4 and from X360 to XB1, not cross platform. Which includes from PE to either of them.